# Symfony Serializer : select group and add extra attributes

Tags: symfony

With Symfony [Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html), I can select group with :

```
[
    'groups' => 'api_index',
]
```

I can select attributes with :

```
[
    'attributes' => [...],
]
```

I can ignore attributes with :

```
[
    'ignored_attributes' => [...],
]
```

But I want to select a group **and add extra attributes**.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Do you mean by extra attributes that do not exist in class?

Answer (score 0):

To add extra Attributes, you need to to use the `@VirtualProperty`.

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

class Entity
{
     private $field;

     /**
      * @VirtualProperty
      * @SerializedName("extra_field")
      */
     public function getextraField()
     {
         // do some logic
         // return "foo";

     }
}
```

your JSON data seems to be something like :

```
{
 ...,
"extra_field":"foo"
}
```

About [@VirtualProperty](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty)